# Entity Framework - check whether has grandchild records

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using asp net core 2.0 and entity framework to access a MySQL database. My model structure looks like

```cs
public class Parent 
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Child> Child { get; set; }
   [NotMapped]
   public virtual bool HasGrandchild  { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Grandchild> Grandchild { get; set; }
}

public class Grandchild
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int ChildId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to check whether there are any records of grandchild in the class `Parent`. I know I can use `Include` and `ThenInclude` to retrieve the child and grandchild. However, the `Grandchild` is really big. I don't want to return them. Alternatively, I could use `for` loop to count the number `Grandchild`. For example,

```cs
List<Parent> p_list = _context.Parent.ToList();
foreach(Parent p in p_list) 
{
    List<Child> c_list = _context.Child
        .Where(c => c.ParentId == p.Id)
        .ToList();
    int NumberOfGrandchild = 0;
    foreach (Child c in c_list) 
    {
        List<Grandchild> gc_list = _context.Grandchild
           .Where(gc =>gc.ChildId == c.Id)
           .ToList();
        NumberOfGrandchild  += gc_list.Count();
    }
    p.HasGrandchild = false;
    if (NumberOfGrandchild > 0) {
        p.HasGrandchild = true;
    }
}
```

The performance of this method is very slow, especially for the big table.

Is there any better method to check whether there are any grandchild records.

Answer (score 2):

```
var parents = _context.Parents
                      .Where(p => p.Children.SelectMany(c => c.Grandchildren).Any());
```

This *should* give you what you're looking for. You want to avoid `Include` as much as possible, because it adds the entire table's columns to the query. (At least it did with <= EF5.)

What's happening here is that you're generating subqueries, the lowest of which will get all `Children` for the `parent`, and see if any `Child` has any `Grandchild`.

If you want to determine if a `Parent` has any `Grandhildren` then you can either move that portion of the `Where` clause, or just have `true` in an anonymous object.

```
var parents = _context.Parents
                      .Select(p => new { // Can be other DTO if you have one
                          Parent = p,
                          HasGrandchildren = p.Children
                                              .SelectMany(c => c.Grandchildren)
                                              .Any()
                      });
```

or

```
var parents = _context.Parents
                      .Where(p => p.Children.SelectMany(c => c.Grandchildren).Any())
                      .Select(p => new {
                          Parent = p,
                          HasGrandchildren = true
                      });
```

The second one probably be a little more performant because it would be able to perform that within a single query. The first *might* be slightly slower of a query, but it would also allow you to get everything.

There are also other ways you could do that with a `GroupBy` if you want to split them between those that do have grandchildren, and those that don't.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now I can select the entry with Grandchildren. But how could I assign it to the variable `HasGrandchild`? I want to return all entities but with an extra field `HasGrandchild`

Comment: @Bangyou Could you loop the above `parents` using foreach and use`item.HasGrandchild=true`?Or you could use `Select()` to manually return Parents.